# Bitwise AND x&y=z, x =?

Tags: math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Just a quick question about the bitwise operator &.

If know that `x & y == z` and I know the value of `y` and `z` is there a way I can calculate the value of `x`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are told that *x* is unique, then no, there is no way of doing it for arbitrary values of *y*. Otherwise, there are 2<sup>n</sup> different solutions to that equation, where *n* is the number of zero bits of *y*.

As an example, let's consider single bit numbers. If *y* is one, then the value of *x* must be the same as *z* (1&1 = 1; 0&1 = 0). If *y* is zero, *z* will also be zero, and *x* can be either one or zero (0&0 = 0; 1&0 = 0).

On many-bit numbers, every zero bit on *y* doubles the number of possible values of *x*, hence 2<sup>n</sup>

Answer (score 5):

No, simple example

```
0&0 = 0
1&0 = 0
```